# What [precisely] is special, algebraically, about fundamental Pell solutions?

Tags: soft-question, recurrence-relations, big-list

I'm asking for a list of algebraic identities which "uniquely identify" (or nearly so) the fundamental solution (or those immediately around it) of a Pell equation.

As a concrete [numerical] example, the solutions to $X^2-2Y^2=\pm1$, alternately, are

$$(1,0),(1,1),(3,2),(7,5),(17,12), \dots$$

Observe that $(3,2),(7,5)$ is the only adjacent pair of solutions where the sum of the larger two elements is equal to the product of the smaller two, *i.e.*, $7+3=10=2 \cdot 5$. So given adjacent solutions $(x_n,y_n)$ and $(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})$, we can state (and hopefully prove) that
$$x_n+x_{n+1} = y_ny_{n+1} \iff (x_n,y_n)=(3,2).$$

Bonus points for algebraic proofs!

Comment: Units in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$ are of the form $\pm\epsilon^n$ for $\epsilon$ the smallest such with $\epsilon>1$ ?!?

Comment: Proving there are no others is straightforward, the solutions grow fast, so product will afterwards always be bigger than sum. I do not think the equality at the beginning has algebraic significance, just the Strong Law of Small Numbers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: If I said to you that $(a,b)$ and $(c,((a+c)/b)$ are two solutions to that equation, you would then know that $(a,b)=(3,2)$, right? That's why I asked this question.

Comment: Yes, but this kind of relationship is not really structural, it is accidental. What was mentioned by Andrea Mori is structural.

Comment: I'm definitely looking for structural relationships.

Comment: Let me clarify: Accidental relationships are fine, too (hence the 'soft question' tag)… but structural relationships are even better.